# Updating User and extended User Profile in one API Call in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a form on my frontend where the user can update some info - part of the fields are supposed to update the default Django `User` Model, while others should update the `User Profile` model, which has a One-To-One Relationship to the User.

I am running the code below but get the following error:

`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_meta'`

**api.py**

```
# Get and Update User API
class UserAPI(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(request.user)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user_data = request.data['user']
        profile_data = request.data['profile']
        user_serializer = self.serializer_class(request.user, data=user_data, partial=True)
        user_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user_serializer.save()

        if profile_data:
            profile_serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
            profile_serializer = ProfileSerializer(request.user.username, data=profile_data, partial=True)
            print(profile_serializer)
            profile_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            profile_serializer.save()

        response = {'user': user_serializer.data, 'profile': profile_serializer.data}
        return Response(response)

# UserProfile API
class ProfileAPI(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    lookup_field = 'user'
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
```

**serializers.py**

```
# User Serializer
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('id', 'username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name')

# Profile Serializer
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  user = serializers.SlugRelatedField(read_only=True, slug_field="username")
  class Meta:
    model = Profile
    fields = '__all__'
```

I am making a patch request in the following format:

```
{
    "user": {
        "username": "testuser"
    },
    "profile": {
        "bio": "hello this is my bio"
    }
}
```

The patch worked when I was only updating the `User` model, however I am not sure if this is the correct way to include the `Profile` model. What would I need to change to make this work?

Comment: You are passing the wrong argument to `ProfileSerializer` it should be the profile instance, not the username which is a string and hence the error you are getting.

Comment: Amazing, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first positional argument to `Serializer` and its subclasses should be the [instance you want to serialize, create, or update](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#saving-instances). In the case of `ModelSerializer` it is a model instance.

You should be therefore passing the `Profile` instance. I assume it is `user.profile`

```
    profile_serializer = ProfileSerializer(request.user.profile, data=profile_data, partial=True)
```